# Are mining pools shares based on prescribed difficulty or the actual difficulty you hash a block with?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, mining-theory, difficulty-share, difficulty

I'm mining Monero as part of a pool (specifically this pool -- https://mixpools.org/xmr/).  I'm using a CryptoNoter package to do the mining.  The pool will send back work taht looks like

```
{"data":"{"type":"job","params":{"blob":"0606ecdd8fd605cbcc264b629c5e203dfa0b7d7334fc2e566b7c6f76186400be6ddab987e3f5c50000000006ca7ff4d00389adf9260f6351ad72a5a1fc1dd271bea01ebdfbb78177e4791205","job_id":"999074511538701","target":"6ab30200"}}
```

I assume "target" means difficulty (if this is wrong, please correct me immediately).  I have two questions.  If I find a nonce that hashes the block at this difficulty,

1. If I find a nonce that hashes the block, reaching the minimum target set above, do I get credit for the minimum target or the target at which I was able to solve the block -- assuming those two things are not the same?
2. Are the number of shares I receive one or is it one times the difficulty set by the job?

Answer (score 1):

You're are correct in assuming target is the same as difficulty

Question 1: You are just credited for the difficulty nothing more. You are set with a threshold to meet to prove you are mining however these shares hold no value unless they are the solution to the current block so you will not be rewarded extra for mining below the threshold, neither will you be paid extra for finding the block solution.

Question 2: The number of "shares" you receive is relative to your difficulty those with a higher difficulty will receive more shares.

Comment: So if difficulty is 100 (to keep things nice and neat) and I submit a hash at thsi difficulty, do I get 100 shares?  The other answer suggests taht it would not be 100, so I wanted to verify I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Dave Yes I believe so and then reward is: `(your shares/total shares) *  block reward` although this may vary with how the pool calculates shares e.g. PPLNS vs PPS

Comment: No. 1 job at difficulty of 100 does not give you 100 shares. It gives you 1 share at a difficulty of 100.

Comment: @jtgrassie care to elaborate how reward is calculated then?

Comment: There are different methods (PPS, PPLS etc) but in either case, it's based on hash difficulty submitted. E.g. if someone submitted 1 job with diff 1000 and someone else submitted 2 jobs with a diff of 600, the second person has submitted more difficulty and thus gets a higher payout. In this example the first person has 1 share with 1000 difficulty and the second with 2 shares of 600. A share is just a batch of N difficulty. Flipping the example, if the first person had submitted a single job of 1500 difficulty, they would get a higher reward.

Comment: @jtgrassie I understand that principle but surely 1 * 1000 = 1000 shares and 2 * 600 = 1200 shares so you can then calculate reward based on total shares.

Comment: No because a single share, in pool parlance, refers to a submission of a given difficulty. Thus, not all shares are equal. When the pool pays out, it pays out based on the difficulty accrued by each miner e.g. difficulty of all the submitted shares per miner.

Answer (score 0):

> If I find a nonce that hashes the block, reaching the minimum target set above, do I get credit for the minimum target or the target at which I was able to solve the block -- assuming those two things are not the same?

It depends on the pool's payout method. For (almost) all of them, you get paid for the difficulty of the job.

> Are the number of shares I receive one or is it one times the difficulty set by the job?

Pools mix these terms up a bit, but you have submitted 1 share and `shares * the job difficulty` hashes. Payout is based on the number of hashes submitted, not the number of shares (otherwise everybody would just mine at a lower difficulty and get higher payouts).

Comment: What's the difference between hashes submitted and shares?

Comment: Pool gives you a job, you hash it and submit it to the pool. If the hash is valid, you are awarded one share at the difficulty of the job.

Comment: If you submit to pool 1 result with actual diff 152, the pools stats should show you have 1 share and 152 hashes. You are paid based on submitted total hashes (it doesn't matter how many shares it took, or what was their individual diff).